# Laravel broadcast not alerting the message on the frontend

Tags: laravel, pusher

I am quite new to this laravel event so I am quite unable to get it done correctly.

I am trying to fire an event to notify the user when the job is completed. So, I am triggering an event at the end of the job as

```
event(new AmenityUploaded($this->data['property_id']));
```

My event looks like:

```
namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;

class AmenityUploaded implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $property_id;

    public function __construct($property_id)
    {
        $this->property_id = $property_id;
    }

    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('channel.amenity.'.$this->property_id);
    }


    public function broadcastAs()
    {
        return 'amenity-uploaded';
    }
}
```

And in `routes/channel.php`

```
Broadcast::channel('channel.amenity.{propertyId}', function ($user, $propertyId) {
//    return $user->id === \App\Models\Property::find($propertyId)->updated_by;
    return true; 
}
```

And in view, I am using javascript as:

### view

```
<script>

    Pusher.logToConsole = true;

    var pusher = new Pusher('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', {
        cluster: 'us3',
        forceTLS: true
    });
    $id = '<?php echo $r->id; ?>';
    var channel = pusher.subscribe(`channel.amenity.${$id}`);
    channel.bind('amenity-uploaded', function(data) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    });


</script>
```

And my `.env` looks like:

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher

PUSHER_APP_ID=xxxxx
PUSHER_APP_KEY=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=us3
```

So, whenever I run the queue with `php artisan queue:work --tries=3`. In the end, I could see that `App\Events\AmenityUploaded` being fired. However, I could not see any alert on the front end.

However, If I try to push notifications from the pusher dashboard, it alerts successfully on the app successfully. While pushing from pusher debug console, I use the channel as `channel.amenity.1` and event as `amenity-uploaded`

## ##Update

I have added a block in event as `broadcastWith`:

```
    public function broadcastWith()
    {
        // This must always be an array. Since it will be parsed with json_encode()
        return [
            'name' => 'Saroj',
            'message' => 'Message',
        ];
    }
```

And, this is successfully showing in pusher dashboard. However, not alerting in the frontend yet.

[image: screenshot]

## update 2

Tried with echo: Added following code in `bootstrap.js`

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo'
import Pusher from "pusher-js"
window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    cluster: 'us3',
    encrypted: true
});
```

And in view:

```
<script>
    $id = '<?php echo $r->id; ?>';


    Echo.channel(`channel.amenity.${$id}`)
        .listen('.amenity-uploaded', (data) => {
            alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        });


</script>
```

Still the same, if fired from the pusher dashboard, an alert will be shown in frontend. After finishing jobs, the event can be seen at the pusher dashboard, however not on the frontend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is that you use only `Pusher` at frontend without `laravel-echo` which should be required to work with private channels. Pusher itself doesn't know that it must authorise, laravel-echo does that out of the box.

This is how I init `Pusher` and `Echo`:

```js
window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');
window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: fromPHP.PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    cluster: fromPHP.PUSHER_CLUSTER,
    encrypted: true
});
```

and this is how I listen for private events:

```js
Echo.private(channel).listen('.amenity-uploaded', data => alert(JSON.stringify(data)));
```

Notice the leading `.` before `amenity-uploaded`. That's required when you customise `broadcastAs` (https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/broadcasting#broadcast-name)

Comment: I am not using vue or react. So, how should I deal with this in that case?

Comment: Also, I am ok if it is not a private channel? I was just following some documents and end up doing this. I am totally ok with the public channel.

Comment: @SarojShrestha you don't need vue or reactjs for this :) I think with public channels your code should work. Generally it looks correct. I'm doing this in exactly the same way except that I don't redefine `broadcastAs` and I'm using `laravel-echo`. So you should look for the issue in some other place. Check that your fired events appear in the Pusher Dashboard. Check the Network tab when you start listening for events.

Comment: I have updated the question could you please check and let me know

Comment: @SarojShrestha I see the name of the channel in pusher dashboard is `private-channel.amenity.4`. When you push an event manually from Pusher does it have the same channel name?

Comment: While pushing manually from server, the channel name was `channel.amenity.4` without `private-`

Comment: @SarojShrestha this is your issue. Laravel backend pushes it into `private-channel.amenity.*` while you listen for `channel.amenity.*`. You must replace `Echo.channel()` with `Echo.private()` as in my example

Comment: I realized my mistake was at event on line `return new PrivateChannel('channel.amenity.'.$this->property_id);` I replaced it with `return ['channel.amenity.'.$this->property_id];` and other seems work fine.

Comment: @SarojShrestha that wasn't an error :) `new PrivateChannel` is the recommended laravel-way of sending events. The error was that you weren't listening for private channel. Though if you want exactly public channel then you can go this way you posted.